# Can't mount smartphone with mtp

Tags: android, ubuntu, mount, smartphone

I want to mount my android to my Laptop (Kubuntu 17.04) using mtp. But whenever I try this, I get the message:

`Unable to create io-slave. klauncher said: Could not find the 'kf5/kio/mtp' plugin.`

but kio is already the newest verion.

Does anybody knows how to fix that problem?

Thanks in advance.